# Ошибка при попытке компиляции приложения Toga в APK файл

Tags: python, android, telegram

В общем осваиваю Toga и Beeware. решал запихнуть в apk файл telegram бот на aiogram.
вот код.

```
import toga
from toga.style import Pack
from toga.constants import COLUMN, CENTER
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
import asyncio
import nest_asyncio


class HelloWorld(toga.App):
    def startup(self):
        nest_asyncio.apply()  # Применить патч nest_asyncio к текущему событийному циклу

        main_box = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN, alignment=CENTER))

        button = toga.Button(
            "Start Bot",
            on_press=self.start_bot,
            style=Pack(padding=5, alignment=CENTER)
        )

        main_box.add(button)

        self.main_window = toga.MainWindow(title=self.formal_name)
        self.main_window.content = main_box
        self.main_window.show()

    def start_bot(self, widget):
        asyncio.create_task(self.run_bot())

    async def run_bot(self):
        bot = Bot(token='TOKEN')
        dp = Dispatcher()

        @dp.message()
        async def on_text_message(msg: types.Message):
            await msg.reply(f"You said: {msg.text}")

        await dp.run_polling(bot)

def main():
    return HelloWorld()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main().main_loop()
```

в терминал PyCharm вводил все что нужно по документации. поскольку я сперва сделал простое android приложение, без telegram бота то порядок был такой: briefcase new, cd helloworld, briefcase dev,briefcase create, briefcase build, briefcase run
после легкого обновления кода briefcase run -u

затем собрал apk файл из кода под документации briefcase create android, briefcase build android, briefcase run android

все сработало.
потом обновил код. импортировал aiogram.
в файле pyproject.toml в requires = [] добавил "aiogram"

далее ввел briefcase run -u

для сборки briefcase create android, briefcase build android

и вот в процессе сборки после ввода briefcase build android все ломается.

ERROR: Failed to install pydantic-core==2.6.3 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/fe/8c9363389f8f303fb151895af83ac30e06c0406779fe188b4281a64e4c50/pydantic_core-2.6.3.tar.gz#sha256=1508f37ba9e3ddc0189e6ff4e2228bd2d3c3a4641cbe8c07177162f76ed696c7 (from pydantic<2.4,>=2.1.1->aiogram->-r requirements.txt (line 1)).
For assistance, please raise an issue at https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues.
Chaquopy: Exit status 1

> Task :app:generateDebugPythonRequirements FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugPythonRequirements'.

> Process 'command 'py'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

To view full details in Android Studio:

- Click the 'Build: failed' caption to the left of this message.
- Then scroll up to see the full output.
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 36s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
Building...

Error while building project.